# LinearLayout elements sizes XML

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I can make something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR59j.jpg) in my layout but I want to put the ok button at right.
But when I try to make this I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0WI6.jpg) instead of.

here is my code(second image).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#00cc33"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#0033cc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="95dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:text="Enter text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="95dip"/>

        <Button
            android:text="OK"
            android:layout_height="95dip"
            android:layout_width="95dip"/>
        
    </LinearLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it's possible to make this using only XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you need to use `RelativeLayout`and specify attributes related to disposition of elements. Try to check here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Thanks !  The solution was easier than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the constraint layout is the best if you use xml.
The 0 dp with constraints can help a lot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Ok" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```